# QGIS Default Vector Layer Style

Tags: qgis, shapefile, default

When I import a shapefile as a vector layer the default setting is always applied for the colouring

[image]

It's always a simple fill with a stroke width of 0.26. Every time I end up changing it to a simple line with a stroke width of 0.66 and choosing a unique color

[image]

If there's any way to make this a default for importing shapefiles that would be a huge time save.

Answer (score 2):

I have not used it before, but you can assign default styles from `Project -> Project Properties -> Default style`:

[image]